# How to login in Angular 4?

Tags: javascript, angular, http

I am new in Angular 4. May be this question is very simple, but I am not able to login when I am trying to login on form button click.

I can get the data from `getAdmin()` when called inside `ngOnInit()`. Below is the code.

**WebService class**

```
getAdmin() {

    return this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/admin/1')
    .map(res => res.json());
  }
```

When I call below method from login button click, I cannot get data and navigate to `home` page.

**LoginComponent**

```
loginUser(e){

    var username = e.target.elements[0].value;
    var password = e.target.elements[1].value;
    console.log(username, password);

    this.web.getAdmin().subscribe((admin) => {
      console.log(admin);
      this.admin = admin;

      if(username == this.admin[0].Username && password == this.admin[0].Password) {   
        localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify(this.admin[0].Username));
        this.router.navigate(["home"]);
      }    
    });

  }
```

If login fails I am redirected to `http://localhost:4200/?uname=admin&psw=admin`

In log I am getting

> XHR failed loading: GET "http://localhost:3000/admin/1".
>
> Navigated to http://localhost:4200/?uname=admin&psw=admin

Debugging the code throws me out of the method without any error in log.

Comment: how you call `loginUser` method? form submit or on anchor click?

Comment: First of all, for security reason, you should send to your server a post with the password in the body. Then, you have to check on the server side if username and password match, and if yes, you have to send an answer to your angular app with the user inside. By this way, you just have to check if user is present or not.

Comment: @PankajParkar, using `<form (submit) = "loginUser($event)">`

Comment: @BenjaminLucidarme, I am going to try your approach also. In the meanwhile please suggest if there is some solution with above approach. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: @Tauqir try below suggested

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `ngSubmit` event instead of `submit`. `submit` will perform default form post on `submit` button click, and where as `ngSubmit` prevents page `post back` and suppress actual form post.

```
<form (ngSubmit) = "loginUser($event)">
```

Comment: I am getting `XHR failed loading: POST "http://localhost:4200/sockjs-node/503/eov5vc30/xhr_streaming?t=1502527731843".
Navigated to http://localhost:4200/?uname=admin&psw=admin
XHR finished loading: GET "http://localhost:4200/sockjs-node/info?t=1502527765786".`

Comment: Thanks a million. I am able to login now. I was missing `import { FormsModule } from "@angular/forms";`  and imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    **FormsModule**,
    HttpModule
  ], in side `app.module.ts`